# Что значит «приложение не использовалось ни разу за два месяца»?

Tags: android, background, android-permissions

У меня приложение связано лишь с тем, чтобы улучшать качество фото в фоне и его Активити нужно лишь для тонкой настройки приложения, от того и вопрос, будет ли засчитано мое приложение как не используемое, если пользователь ни разу не открыл Активити за 2 месяца?